# Transfer an object from one NHibernate session two another session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Two `NHibernate` sessions are already created, I create a new model object and save it with an `Id` in **`session1`**, then I use `Merge` method from **`session2`** to commit its changes.

```
// session1, NHibernate
var obj1 = new FooModel();
session1.Save(obj1, Guid.NewId());

// session2, NHibernte
session2.Merge(obj1);
session2.Commit();

// and finally
session1.Commit();
```

and the result I think is kind of unexpected! by running code above NHibernate will insert **2** records with different Id's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is because the object in `session2` is transient when it's added? It shouldn't be because you're allocating the key in the call to `Save()`, however the behaviour you're observing fits with that situation.

If you change the code to:

```
// session1, NHibernate
var obj1 = new FooModel();

session1.Save(obj1, Guid.NewId());
session1.Commit();

// session2, NHibernte
session2.Merge(obj1);
session2.Commit();
```

What's the effect?

Comment: This might work, but I want to detach transient object in `session1` and attach it in `session2`.

Comment: Detach = `Evict()`. Once saved and/or committed, the object will not be transient any longer though.

Comment: @DavidOsborne You are right, but I think `Evict` won't work unless I `Flush` the session, Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you actually want to do. Why do you need to save the object in the first session but only commit in the second? Why can't you just save and commit in the second?